# Multiple WordPress Multisite under one EC2 instance (AWS)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, multisite

We are trying to to configure the DNS routing for our multisites under one EC2 instance.

Specifically we are setting up DEV, TEST, and UAT environments of a WordPress Multisite. We only just have 2 sites on this network; the main site and one network site.

Now I have successfully migrated a copy (using Duplicator Pro) of our production site (on a different EC2 instance) to our DEV and the WordPress Multisite works. We have set the wildcard entries on our route53 for this (will provide a screenshot later).

But when I migrated the same copy to TEST and UAT, the main site works but the network site is not working and only redirects to our DEV site.

Can you suggest the correct way of setting up the DNS and wildcards for this setup? Or it's not possible and should be on separate EC2 instances for each environment?

Comment: What's Webserver you using? Apache or Nginx?
Do you have virtualhost setup and enable for all sites?

Answer (score 0):

Check your setting in `wp_options` table for different environment. Whethere its set to dev URL or not.

```sql
select * from wp_options where option_name like 'siteurl';
```

OR

inside `wp-config.php`

```php
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/xyz');
```

it should be different for different environment. If possible give your URL sample.

You can use single EC2 for multiple wordpress instance. You have to set server configuration file to accept domain request under 80 or 443 port.

```
/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name1/public/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name1/public/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have searched the entire database and there are no existence of the dev URL anywhere.

It's under /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, the virtual hosts are assigned to port 80 and the servername and documentroot are all good as you have indicated above. They are pointing to the correct server name and root folders.