# EC2 instance web server site as a subdomain of a Squarespace site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, squarespace

I have a website on Squarespace: www.example.com

Squarespace doesn't allow custom code, so I developed a web app with advanced functionality on an EC2 instance that currently has an elastic IP address: 12.34.56.78.

Is it possible to connect the two in that the web app at 12.34.56.78 can be displayed when users visit webapp.example.com? Is that a subdomain?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you could setup [Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html) for that.

Comment: if you using apache you can set up in two domain for same code. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539301/multiple-wordpress-multisite-under-one-ec2-instance-aws/59551561#59551561

Comment: domain name is registered with Google Domains ... parent domain is pointing to Squarespace ... is there a way to point a subdomain to EC2?